# yum not finding correct package version of graphviz

Tags: rhel, yum

I'm trying to install graphviz version 2.38 on my RHEL workstation. I saved [graphviz-rhel.repo](http://www.graphviz.org/graphviz-rhel.repo) in `/etc/yum.repos.d` as instructed, but when I run `sudo yum list available 'graphviz*'`, the only version it finds is 2.30, which has a bug that has been fixed in later versions so I need to have 2.38. I think the links in graphviz-rhel.repo might be broken which is why yum doesn't find the latest stable packages, but I'm not 100% sure. Thank you.

Comment: What is your RHEL workstation version? The version depends ond this. The repo files uses $relesver in the path. Some releasever only get older versions...

Comment: Other idea: Did you du a `yum update` before searching?

Comment: @Tobias `yum update` upgrades packages, it's not the same as `apt-get update`.

Comment: You are right. I just wanted to ensure, that the repositories are refreshed. Better would be `yum makecache`.

Comment: Did you enable the repo?

Answer (score 1):

Use `yum repolist all` to see all repos. Use then `yum-config-manager --enable repository-id` to enable your graphviz repo.

If your repo is not listened try `yum-config-manager --add-repo http://www.graphviz.org/graphviz-rhel.repo` to add your repo.

Comment: I tried both of these. When I used `yum repolist all` I got a few disabled graphviz repos. Then I tried enabling them all but on the status it said 0 after the word "enabled" which I'm guessing means that it's enabled but has no packages? I confirmed this to be true by running `yum list available 'graphviz*'` again and the only version listed after enabling them were still 2.30.

Comment: I think the problem might be that this repo doesn't exist for my particular OS and architecture. When I type `yum repolist all` I get this which is caused by the graphviz-rhel.repo I added to `/etc/yum.repo.d`: `http://www.graphviz.org/pub/graphviz/development/redhat/el7Workstation/x86_64/debug/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found`

Comment: Ah. You have this version. Yes, theres is no repo for it. Check this: http://www.graphviz.org/pub/graphviz/development/redhat/

Comment: You can try the source rpm from graphviz.org. There is one for Red Hat. Howto: http://www.itechlounge.net/2012/12/linux-how-to-install-source-rpm-on-rhelcentos/ PS: I have no expereiance with this - just a tip.